# Contributors should only access home page

Tags: homepage

My site's contributors are successfully registered.

However, when they log in I want them to be directed directly to the home page of the site on not to their profile, because they do not need it.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can use the **[login_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)** filter to do this.

Use the code below in your active theme's **`functions.php`** file.

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for contributors
        if( in_array( "contributor", $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the home page $home_url should contain the home page url
            return $home_url;
        } else {
            return $redirect_to;
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, does this work the same for role: Subscriber?

Comment: yes it works the same way, just replace the **role** accordingly like `if( in_array( "subscriber", $user->roles ) ) {` .

Comment: what do you mean by "it needed some time to take affect?"

Comment: It wasnt immediately executed as such on our web server. Maybe due to caching reasons.